# How can I emulate Bluetooth mouse wheel event on android emulator running android 4.1

Tags: android, android-widget, android-hardware

Now I don't have any android 4.1 device,but the boss ask to process the bluetooth mouse's wheel event in my android application.

```
public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getButtonState() == MotionEvent.BUTTON_TERTIARY)
    {
      //This is the wheel event case,
      //but I don't know what the other things about wheel rolling forward or rolling back,
      //who can tell me how to process the wheel rolling forward and back status
    }
}
```

Please help me, thanks!